# Use .txt files with email list and print it on index

Tags: php, html

I just want basic guidance.

I have a .txt file that contains some emails presented in this format:

```
<example1@example.com>
<example2@example.com>
```

I would like somehow, print on my index page the numbers of emails registered on this .txt file

Like "we have [Number printed from .txt file] subscribers so far"

thanks for the help

Comment: is this intended for a live site? if so, any reason you're not using a database? text files are a lot of work and need to be fully protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is count emails inside file that contains only email addresses, than you can just count `@` in string.

```
$emails = file_get_content('email.txt');
$count = substr_count('@', $emails);

echo "We have {$count} subscribers so far";
```

Comment: thanks @Justinas. One quick question, why if I'm inserting 

    <?php
        $emails = file_get_content('myfile.txt');
  $count = substr_count('@', $emails);
  print "We have {$count} subscribers so far";
        ?>


On my html-php file inside the body, nothing is being displayed? thanks in advance!

Comment: hello @Justinas I've tried echo and nothing, no errors btw. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

If all of the email addresses are in seperate lines, you could just count the number of lines:

```
function getNumberOfSubs(){
  $filePath = '~/subs.txt'; // Example Path
  $counter = 0;

  $file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
  if ($file){
    while($nextLine = fgets($file) !== false){
      $counter++;
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $counter;
  } else {
    return 'Could not open file!';
  }
}
```

How to use it:

```
$count = $this->getNumberOfSubs();
echo "We have currently {$count} subs.";
```

If this is just a demo and not live, i recommend to use a database instead, which is also much more easy to use as you can add, remove, modify and count the emails as you wish.

Comment: Thanks @Tobias F so at the end it should look like this?

     <?php
        function getNumberOfSubs(){
        $filePath = 'emaillist-5g04kNwj69.txt'; // Example Path
        $counter = 0;

        $file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
        if ($file){
        while($nextLine = fgets($file) !== false){
        $counter++;
        }
        fclose($file);
        return $counter;
        } else {
        return 'Could not open file!';
        }
        }

  echo "We have {$counter} subscribers so far";
        ?>

Comment: Thanks @Tobias F and yes, is just for learning purposes. At the end is not working neither:( I just inserted it like that example:

   <?php
        function getNumberOfSubs(){
  $filePath = '~/subs.txt'; // Example Path
  $counter = 0;

  $file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
  if ($file){
  while($nextLine = fgets($file) !== false){
  $counter++;
     }
  fclose($file);
  return $counter;
    } else {
    return 'Could not open file!';
    }
  }
  $count = $this->getNumberOfSubs();
        echo "We have currently {$count} subs.";
        ?>

Comment: No, no error showing:( is just that is not rendering the message nor the number. How can I upload again all the code to show?